# get value of the selected checkbox from matrix table

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have designed a matrix table using html in asp.net web form so I want if  user click the checkbox immediately display the name of the selected row and also of the selected column. The output it should look like this : **Chlor-Alkali**  **Relationship** see the screenshot below but it return the row index and column index.

[image]

here is the code below:

Comment: IF you want people to help, you need to post code that you have already tried, to get this to work, then once people have seen that you put forth some effort they will tend to want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the checked inputs using document selector and checked attribute:

```
function myFunction() {
  // get all checkboxes
  const checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("selectableType");
  var result = "";

  // iterate over them
  for (var box = 0; box < checkBoxes.length; box ++) {

    // check if single checkbox is checked
    if (checkBoxes[box].checked === true) {

      // and do your needed magic here :D
      console.log(">", checkBoxes[box].value);
      result += checkBoxes[box].value + "\n";
    }
  }

  // just an example to show results
  alert (result === "" ? "No result" : "Selected inputs are\n" + result);
}
```

[Check here a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/2k5Lkjne/13/)